# How to increase command history size for tcl shell

Tags: tcl, history

I am using tcl8.6 and I find that the command that recorded in 'history' is only 20.
How can I increase the command size that record in 'history' for tcl shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `history keep $biggerNumber` -- http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/history.htm

Depending on what platform you use, you might like [`rlwrap`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/rlwrap.1.html) which gives you all the readline line editing goodies: arrow keys for history, etc.

```sh
alias tclsh='rlwrap tclsh'
```

Or, [`Tkcon`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tkcon) is a good choice too.